# How to order rows in a table within partitions?

Tags: sql, db2

I am using DB2 to take a table, split it into partitions and then order rows within each partition. The table I have is like:

```
ID        DATE                 EVENT
--        ----                 -----
01        1999-06-01           a
01        1999-06-01           b
01        2006-01-01           a
01        2011-12-31           c
02        1999-01-01           a
02        2003-01-01           a
02        2003-01-01           b            
02        2009-11-12           b
```

where I want to order it to get the following...

```
ID        DATE                 EVENT        SEQUENCE
--        ----                 -----        --------
01        1999-06-01           a            1
01        1999-06-01           b            1
01        2006-01-01           a            2  
01        2011-12-31           c            3 
02        1999-01-01           a            1
02        2003-01-01           a            2 
02        2003-01-01           b            2
02        2009-11-12           b            3
```

so I am trying:

```
select a.*, row_number() over(partition by ID,order by DATE) from mytable a
```

which gives me:

```
  ID        DATE                 EVENT        SEQUENCE
    --        ----                 -----        --------
    01        1999-06-01           a            1
    01        1999-06-01           b            2
    01        2006-01-01           a            3  
    01        2011-12-31           c            4 
    02        1999-01-01           a            1
    02        2003-01-01           a            2 
    02        2003-01-01           b            3
    02        2009-11-12           b            4
```

where as you can see, even though a consecutive row may have the same date as the previous row, this is ignored and the SEQUENCE column is iterated.

How do I ensure that if the next row has the same date that the sequence is preserved until a row with a later date appears?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, the `row_number()` function would not return the same number for different rows within the window. You need to use the `dense_rank()` function.

By the way, your query has a syntax error, and it is not a good idea to use reserved words ('DATE' in this case) for column names.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `DENSE_RANK` function instead, which gives you an option of assigning the same rank, if two rows have the same values, as below:

```
select a.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE DESC) from mytable a;
```

**References**:

[Using OLAP specifications](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/sqlp/rbafyolap.htm)